# Can I write a mysqli query with an IF statement in the WHERE clause with GROUP BY? OR Can I perform more than one query in my function?

Tags: php, mysqli

Currently, I have a mysql db table structured as shown below (Table which $sql executes against.).  I am running the php function (Current Code:) that produces an array which I output into html.

Current result: One row per per Model Code based on inputs of $location, $age1, and $age2.

```
 +----+-----+-----------+----------+----+-------------+-----------+
 | Yr | Mdl | Mdl Code  | Mdl Line | Ct | Total Gross | Avg Gross |
 +----+-----+-----------+----------+----+-------------+-----------+
 |2017| MDX | YD7H7HKNW |  AWDADV  | 3  | $ 5,324.54  |$ 1,774.85 |
 |2017| RDX | ZD7H8HKNW |  ADV     | 1  | $ 2,324.54  |$ 2,324.54 | 
 +----+-----+-----------+----------+----+-------------+-----------+
```

**I need to produce an output of multiple rows per Model Code with age buckets of 1-30, 31-60, 61-90, and >= 91.**

```
 +-------+----+-----+-----------+----------+----+-------------+-----------+
 | Age B | Yr | Mdl | Mdl Code  | Mdl Line | Ct | Total Gross | Avg Gross |
 +-------+----+-----+-----------+----------+----+-------------+-----------+
 |1 - 30 |2017| MDX | YD7H7HKNW |  AWDADV  | 3  | $ 6,324.54  |$ 2,108.18 |
 |31 -60 |2017| MDX | YD7H7HKNW |  AWDADV  | 2  | $ 3,324.54  |$ 1,662.27 |
 +-------+----+-----+-----------+----------+----+-------------+-----------+
```

**I'm not sure of how to do this so, any help would be greatly appreciated.**

**Current Code:**

```
function ageBucket($location, $age1, $age2){

global $con;
$ageBucket = array();
foreach (modelCodeList($location) as $mc) {

    $sql = "SELECT `Model Code`, `Year`, `Model`, `Model Line`, COUNT(`Model Code`) AS 'Count' , SUM(`GROSS`) AS 'Total Gross', AVG(`GROSS`) AS 'Avg Gross' FROM `inv_current` WHERE `Location` = '$location' AND `Model Code`= '$mc'  AND `Age` BETWEEN '$age1' AND '$age2' GROUP BY `Age` BETWEEN '$age1' AND '$age2'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $ageBucket[] = $row;
    }
}

usort($ageBucket, function ($a, $b) {
    if($b['Avg Gross'] == $a['Avg Gross']) return 0;
    return $b['Avg Gross'] < $a['Avg Gross'] ? -1 : 1;
});

return $ageBucket;
}
```

**Table which $sql executes against.**

```
 +----------+------------+-----+------+---------+------------+-------+
 | Location | Model Code | Age | Year |  Model  | Model Line | GROSS |
 +----------+------------+-----+------+---------+------------+-------+
 |        3 | TB3H3HJNW  | 241 | 2017 | RDX     | FWD        |   328 |
 |        3 | KC1F9HKNW  | 225 | 2017 | RLX     | ADV        | -1181 |
 |        3 | DE2F7HKNW  | 225 | 2017 | ILX     | TECH       |   896 |
 |        3 | NC1B0HEW   | 205 | 2017 | NSX     |            |   734 |
 |        8 | YD3H8HKNW  | 178 | 2017 | MDX     | ADV        |    24 |
 |        8 | DE2F7HKNW  | 178 | 2017 | ILX     | TECH       |  -724 |
 |        8 | DE2F8HJW   | 171 | 2017 | ILX     | PREMAS     |  -381 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  | 171 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |  -213 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  | 169 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |  -776 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  | 169 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |   244 |
 |        3 | YD4H5HKNW  | 163 | 2017 | MDX     | 4TECH      |  -914 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  | 163 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |    70 |
 |        8 | YD4H5HKNW  | 163 | 2017 | MDX     | 4TECH      | -1165 |
 |        8 | DE2F7HKNW  | 157 | 2017 | ILX     |            | -1107 |
 |        8 | NC1B0HEW   | 156 | 2017 | NSX     |            |  -863 |
 |        8 | DE2F8HJW   | 156 | 2017 | ILX     | PREMAS     |  -561 |
 |        3 | TB3H5HKNW  | 156 | 2017 | RDX     | TECH       |   139 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  | 146 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |     8 |
 |        3 | YD3H8HKNW  | 143 | 2017 | MDX     | ADV        |     5 |
 |        3 | DE2F7HKNW  | 140 | 2017 | ILX     | TECH       |   491 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  | 140 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |  -230 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  | 140 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |  -764 |
 |        8 | YD4H5HKNW  | 134 | 2017 | MDX     | 4TECH      |   113 |
 |        8 | DE2F7HJNW  | 134 | 2017 | ILX     | PREM       |   755 |
 |        3 | TB3H7HKNW  | 129 | 2017 | RDX     | ADV        |   -21 |
 |        3 | TB3H3HJNW  | 127 | 2017 | RDX     |            |   905 |
 |        3 | TB3H3HJNW  | 127 | 2017 | RDX     |            |  -664 |
 |        3 | TB3H3HJNW  | 127 | 2017 | RDX     |            |  -112 |
 |        8 | DE2F3HJW   | 121 | 2017 | ILX     |            |   170 |
 |        8 | DE2F7HKNW  | 120 | 2017 | ILX     | TECH       |  -412 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  | 120 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |   341 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  | 120 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       | -1026 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  | 120 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |   653 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  | 119 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |   279 |
 |        3 | DE2F8HJW   | 119 | 2017 | ILX     | PREMAS     |  -207 |
 |        3 | YD3H3HJNW  | 118 | 2017 | MDX     |            |  -662 |
 |        8 | YD3H3HJNW  | 113 | 2017 | MDX     |            |   178 |
 |        8 | DE2F7HJNW  | 111 | 2017 | ILX     | PREM       |   701 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  | 111 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       | -1034 |
 |        8 | YD4H5HKNW  | 111 | 2017 | MDX     | 4TECH      |  -502 |
 |        3 | YD3H3HJNW  | 111 | 2017 | MDX     |            |    16 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  | 111 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |   853 |
 |        3 | YD3H8HKNW  | 108 | 2017 | MDX     |            |   362 |
 |        3 | YD4H8HKNW  | 105 | 2017 | MDX     | 4ADV       |   525 |
 |        8 | DE2F7HKNW  | 100 | 2017 | ILX     | TECH       |   149 |
 |        8 | DE2F7HKNW  | 100 | 2017 | ILX     | TECH       |   167 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  |  97 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |   326 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  |  97 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |   586 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  |  97 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |  -118 |
 |        3 | DE2F7HJNW  |  94 | 2017 | ILX     | PREM       |  -305 |
 |        3 | DE2F7HJNW  |  93 | 2017 | ILX     | PREM       |  -609 |
 |        3 | YD3H8HKNW  |  87 | 2017 | MDX     |            |  -263 |
 |        8 | TB3H3HJNW  |  86 | 2017 | RDX     |            |    20 |
 |        8 | YD4H8HKNW  |  79 | 2017 | MDX     | 4ADV       |     4 |
 |        8 | DE2F3HJW   |  79 | 2017 | ILX     |            |   265 |
 |        8 | TB3H5HKNW  |  79 | 2017 | RDX     | TECH       |  -470 |
 |        3 | UB1F3JJW   |  78 | 2018 | TLX 2.4 | TLX2.4     | -1161 |
 |        3 | UB1F5JKNW  |  78 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH 2.4   | -1073 |
 |        3 | UB2F5JKNW  |  78 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |  -141 |
 |        3 | UB1F5JKNW  |  78 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH 2.4   |   789 |
 |        8 | UB2F5JKNW  |  78 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |   296 |
 |        8 | UB1F3JJW   |  78 | 2018 | TLX 2.4 | TLX 2.4    |   -10 |
 |        8 | UB2F5JKNW  |  78 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |   871 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  |  78 | 2017 | MDX     |            | -1170 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  |  76 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |  -627 |
 |        3 | UB1F5JKNW  |  76 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH 2.4   |  -711 |
 |        3 | UB2F6JKNW  |  76 | 2018 | TLX     | A-SPEC     | -1100 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  |  72 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |  -529 |
 |        8 | YD4H5HKNW  |  72 | 2017 | MDX     | 4TECH      |  -254 |
 |        8 | UB2F3JJW   |  72 | 2018 | TLX     |            |   632 |
 |        8 | UB2F6JKNW  |  72 | 2018 | TLX     | A-SPEC     |  -801 |
 |        8 | UB1F3JJW   |  72 | 2018 | TLX 2.4 | TLX 2.4    | -1165 |
 |        3 | UB2F5JKNW  |  72 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |  -482 |
 |        3 | DE2F7HKNW  |  70 | 2017 | ILX     | TECH       |   421 |
 |        3 | UB2F5JKNW  |  70 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |   288 |
 |        3 | UB1F5JKNW  |  70 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH 2.4   |  -144 |
 |        8 | YD7H7HKNW  |  68 | 2017 | MDX     |            |  -678 |
 |        8 | DE2F7HKNW  |  66 | 2017 | ILX     |            |  -993 |
 |        8 | YD4H9HKNW  |  64 | 2017 | MDX     | 4ADVENT    |  -934 |
 |        8 | UB2F5JKNW  |  64 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH V6    |   298 |
 |        3 | UB1F3JJW   |  64 | 2018 | TLX 2.4 | TLX 2.4    |  -609 |
 |        3 | UB1F5JKNW  |  64 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH 2.4   |   484 |
 |        3 | UB1F5JKNW  |  64 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH 2.4   |   570 |
 |        3 | TB3H5JKNW  |  64 | 2018 | RDX     | TECH       |   675 |
 |        8 | TB3H7JKNW  |  64 | 2018 | RDX     | ADV        |    25 |
 |        8 | UB2F5JKNW  |  64 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |  -853 |
 |        8 | YD3H8HKNW  |  64 | 2017 | MDX     |            |  -593 |
 |        8 | DE2F3HJW   |  62 | 2017 | ILX     |            |   -16 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  |  58 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |   252 |
 |        3 | YD4H8HKNW  |  58 | 2017 | MDX     | 4ADV       |   977 |
 |        3 | YD3H3HJNW  |  58 | 2017 | MDX     |            |   -50 |
 |        3 | UB1F3JJW   |  58 | 2018 | TLX 2.4 | TLX 2.4    |   848 |
 |        8 | UB1F5JKNW  |  58 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH 2.4   |    79 |
 |        8 | TB3H7JKNW  |  58 | 2018 | RDX     | ADV        |  -299 |
 |        8 | UB2F5JKNW  |  58 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |   708 |
 |        8 | UB2F5JKNW  |  58 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |  -813 |
 |        3 | TB4H3JJNW  |  58 | 2018 | RDX     | 4RDX       |  -370 |
 |        3 | YD3H5HKNW  |  56 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |  -824 |
 |        3 | YD3H3HJNW  |  56 | 2017 | MDX     |            |   462 |
 |        3 | UB2F5JKNW  |  56 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |  -676 |
 |        8 | TB3H7JKNW  |  56 | 2018 | RDX     | ADV        |   610 |
 |        8 | TB3H7JKNW  |  56 | 2018 | RDX     | ADV        |  -556 |
 |        8 | TB3H5JKNW  |  56 | 2018 | RDX     | TECH       | -1058 |
 |        8 | TB3H3JJNW  |  56 | 2018 | RDX     |            |  -192 |
 |        3 | TB3H7JKNW  |  56 | 2018 | RDX     | ADV        |   -96 |
 |        3 | YD4H5HKNW  |  55 | 2017 | MDX     | 4TECH      |  -842 |
 |        3 | UB1F3JJW   |  55 | 2018 | TLX 2.4 | TLX 2.4    |   948 |
 |        3 | TB3H7JKNW  |  55 | 2018 | RDX     | ADV        |   484 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  |  51 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |    31 |
 |        8 | YD3H5HKNW  |  51 | 2017 | MDX     | TECH       |   694 |
 |        8 | UB2F5JKNW  |  51 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |   352 |
 |        8 | UB2F5JKNW  |  51 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |  -260 |
 |        3 | UB1F3JJW   |  51 | 2018 | TLX 2.4 | TLX 2.4    |   454 |
 |        3 | UB1F5JKNW  |  51 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH 2.4   |  -245 |
 |        8 | UB2F5JKNW  |   1 | 2018 | TLX     | TECH       |   722 |
 +----------+------------+-----+------+---------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: MySQL does not excel at *analytic functions*. There is no `over` function for example like in some other RDBMS. [This article](https://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/) might be worth a read.

Comment: Let me know if my solution is remotely helpful, if it throws errors, or if I didn't even understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for your post.  It was very helpful.  I will post my result below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunt Jamaima thank you for you sql statement above.  When I ran it against my db the user defined variable of `group` returned null as seen here.

[image]

Consequently, I moved ceiling(`Age`/30) from GROUP BY to the UDV in the SELECT.

```
SELECT (@c:=ceiling(`Age`/30)) as `group`, `Model Code`, `Year`, `Model`, `Model Line`, COUNT(`Model Code`) AS 'Count' , SUM(`GROSS`) AS 'Total Gross', AVG(`GROSS`) AS 'Avg Gross' FROM `inv_current` WHERE `Location` = 30 AND `Model Code`= 'CC15706'  group by `group`
```

Here is the result of this sql statement.

[image]

With this successful sql result I found I still needed to modify my PHP function by changing the mysqli_fetch_assoc() use in my first attempt, to mysqli_multi_query() as shown below.

An important note regarding the multi_query, much of the online documentation I found incorrectly had the mysqli_free_result() working on the mysqli_free_result($connection) rather than the mysqli_free_result($result).  This error produced the following parameter error.

```
Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result
```

It wasn't until I went back to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) that I realized the error.  The manual states, "mysqli_free_result — Frees the memory associated with a **result**".

In any case here is the result of several hours of trial and error.  Most of which is due to my need to learn more about programming. I could not have produced my desired output without the help of Aunt Jamamia and others who took the time to post here and elsewhere online.  I hope others will find this snippet useful.

```
function ageBuckets($location, $model_code){

global $con;
$ageBuckets = array();

// foreach (modelCodeList($location) as $mc) {

    $sql = "SELECT (@c:=ceiling(`Age`/30)) as `Age Bucket`, `Model Code`, `Year`, `Model`, `Model Line`, COUNT(`Model Code`) AS 'Count' , SUM(`GROSS`) AS 'Total Gross', AVG(`GROSS`) AS 'Avg Gross' FROM `inv_current` WHERE `Location` = '$location' AND `Model Code`= '$model_code' group by `Year`, `Age Bucket` ";


    if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $sql)) {

        do {

            if($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $ageBuckets[] = $row;
                }

                mysqli_free_result($result);
            }

        } while(mysqli_more_results($con) && mysqli_next_result($con));
    }

// }

return $ageBuckets;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't exactly it, but it's kind of close. You can change your $sql to:

```
SELECT (@s:=@s+1)*30 as `group`, `Model Code`, `Year`, `Model`, `Model Line`, COUNT(`Model Code`) AS 'Count' , SUM(`GROSS`) AS 'Total Gross', AVG(`GROSS`) AS 'Avg Gross' FROM `inv_current` WHERE `Location` = '$location' AND `Model Code`= '$mc'  group by ceiling(`age`/30)
```

This should have an output like:

```
+-------+----+-----+-----------+----------+----+-------------+-----------+
 | Age B | Yr | Mdl | Mdl Code  | Mdl Line | Ct | Total Gross | Avg Gross |
 +-------+----+-----+-----------+----------+----+-------------+-----------+
 |30     |2017| MDX | YD7H7HKNW |  AWDADV  | 3  | $ 6,324.54  |$ 2,108.18 |
 |60     |2017| MDX | YD7H7HKNW |  AWDADV  | 2  | $ 3,324.54  |$ 1,662.27 |
 +-------+----+-----+-----------+----------+----+-------------+-----------+
```